# How do I calculate the centroid point of multiple longitude and latitude data points in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, distance, centroid, geographic-distance

I have a dataset with various longitude and latitude datapoints. I would like to develop a centroid or "average" of those  longitude and latitude coordinates in bigquery at a specific level of granularity.

**Example of Current Data:**

| ID | LONG | LAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | -71.23403 | 42.01979 |
| 101 | -91.469621 | 44.867211 |
| 102 | 78.8952716 | 38.4022661 |
| 102 | 80.8518668 | 35.3152386 |

**Desired Output** (output centroid is made up)

| ID | CENTROID_LONG | CENTROID_LAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | -71.23403 | 42.01979 |
| 102 | -91.469621 | 44.867211 |

Where the values above are aggregated to a centroid lat and long number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below

```
select id, st_union_agg(st_geogpoint(long, lat)) points,
  st_centroid(st_union_agg(st_geogpoint(long, lat))) centroid
from your_table
group by id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

which is visualized as

[image]

Comment: This works! I wanted to ask, does average also work? I tried it out and got a reasonable "centroid" by just averaging lat/long of both IDs

Comment: I think even for two points  - average will not be the same as when using respective geo function. but for more then two - for sure will be different - very different!

Comment: Thank you, I see the values are listed as POINT(-91.4770186504064 40.1330453849171), is there any way I can extract these two values and place it into two different columns which would indicate the lat and the long.

Comment: I will be using the values to calculate linear distance and also potentially placing it on a map.

Comment: to get lat and long in separate columns  - you can use [`ST_X(centroid)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_x) and [`ST_Y(centroid)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_y)

Comment: Great answer, note that there is `ST_CENTROID_AGG` function, that avoids constly `ST_UNION`:

`select id, st_centroid_agg(st_geogpoint(long, lat)) centroid
from your_table
group by id `